# How synchronize Keycloak themes and providers in domain clustered mode?

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I'm trying to install a cluster of Keycloak instances in domain clustered mode. I have already configured `domain.xml`, `host-master.xml` and `host-slave.xml` files and I have a fonctionnal Keycloak.

I wanted to know if it's possible, with Wildfly and Keycloak, to synchronize the `providers` and `themes` directories directly from the master domain controller to the host controllers.

In other words, is it possible to change files on `themes` and `provider` directories on the domain controller and having those changes automatically deployed on all host controllers (all actives Keycloak instances) with wildfly configuration ?

I have tried to use an unmanaged deployment with no success : it seems to tell to instances to deploy the content of a repository but it doesn't copy the content of the domain directory to host directories.

We have thought to use a script to do this but if Wildfly allows this, it should be better.

Thanks a lot for your advices.